# Kendo UI Grid: Hide detailInit grid if it does not have any data

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using the KendoUI hierarchy grid to display parent/child data.

I am able to fill everything out properly and get the grids to populate, but in some cases the parent data does not have corresponding child records.

When this happens, the child grid headers are still displayed with no corresponding records.  I would like to hide the grid completely, or at least not show the headers  (which would render almost the same thing).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You did not share any code so we can have a better idea what exactly is your current setup - there are different approach depending on your configuration.

Do you have a property of the master grid model which you can use to determine if you have child records or not?

If there is no such property you will need to initialize your child Grid and it should perform a request. Based on the response you can use the [dataBound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#databound) event and hide the Grid if there are no records.
Or you can do the opposite - you can make the Grid hidden initially and show it if there are any records when the **dataBound** event occurs.

If you have property in the master row that indicates there are no child records you can use the [detailInit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#detailinit) event of the Grid to completely remove the child Grid or hide it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to hide the subgrid in some cases (depending on one variable). What I did was:

```
detailInit: function (e) {
                    if (globalVariable == "SomeValue") {
                        div = jQuery("<div class = 'addMaterialVendors'/>");
                        subGrid = MethodToCreateSubgrid(div, variables, e.data);
                        div.appendTo(e.detailCell);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".k-hierarchy-cell").remove();
                        $(".k-hierarchy-col").remove();
                    }
                },
```